# Do objects destructors automatically get called when they go out of scope?

Tags: c++, memory-management, resource-management

I'm reading through Scott Meyers Effective C++ and I have a question regarding resource management. In the book, he suggests that one should use the auto_ptr object to manage memory as it will automatically call the destructor of the object it points to when it goes out of scope. Here is the example provided:

```
void f() {
    Investment *pInv = createInvestment();    // Call factory function
    ...                                       // use pInv
    delete pInv;                              // release object
}
```

He claims that this is potentially problematic because there could be a number of things that happen in the `...` that would prevent the method from reaching `delete pInv` (premature return statement, thrown exception, ...). This is the code that he suggests in its place

```
void f() {
    std::auto_ptr<Investment> pInv(createInvestment()); // call factory function
    ...                                                 // use pInv as before
}                                                       // automatically delete pInv
```

This works because no matter what happens `pInv` will be deleted when it goes out of scope.

My question is this: why wouldn't the destructor of `pInv` be called when it goes out of scope in the first code block. Wouldn't a premature return statement push the object out of scope, or is that not how garbage collection works in C++?

Hopefully I have explained my confusion well enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"is that not how garbage collection works in C++?"* In C++, there is no garbage collection.

Comment: `pInv` is a scalar type, not a class type, so it doesn't have a destructor. The lifetime of `pInv` still ends at the end of the scope of course, but there's nothing to do.

Comment: So is the automatic deletion of auto_ptr when it goes out of scope a feature that is limited to only auto_ptr?

Comment: `one should use the auto_ptr object to manage memory` No.

Comment: @wKavey: What, why? No. All class types have destructors that are run at the end of object lifetime.

Comment: Are you actually confused about what the type of `pInv` is?

Comment: Please don't use `auto_ptr` in modern C++. Use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I might understand now(?): Because (in the first example) `pInv` is a pointer to an object the pointer is destroyed when leaving scope but the `Investment` object remains allocated somewhere - while in the second example `pInv` is an `auto_ptr` which frees both itself and the `Investment` object it points to upon leaving scope?

Comment: Effective C++ is an *excellent* book, so it's good that you're reading it. But, as people have pointed out here, it is a bit out of date. It refers to the C++03 standard, which has been effectively superseded by the C++11 standard. In C++03, you used `std::auto_ptr` as a smart pointer class to automatically manage the lifetime of objects being pointed to by pointers (such as those you create with `new`). However, in C++11, you use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Exact same concept, though. I believe that the answers to the duplicate question will clear up your confusion.

Comment: @wKavey: That's kind of getting there, yes. In the second example, the destructor of the class-type object executes at the end of the object's lifetime and can thus perform arbitrary, user-defined actions. `auto_ptr` is designed so that the destructor destroys the dynamically allocated object that the autoptr is holding.